# typegoose: How to find movies whose director or producer is Michael bay in typegoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I'm trying to return from getMovies endpoint all movies whose director or producer was michael bay.

```
async getMovies(user: User): Promise<Movies[]> {
    return await this.movieModel
    .find({ director: user.name }
```

so the above returns all movies by director
I wanted to put an or statement where also movies produced by the same user will be returned
`sample movie object`

movie: {
    name: "movieName",
    director: "michael bay",
    producer: " other producer"
}

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use the [`$or` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for querys

```
async getMovies(user: User): Promise<Movies[]> {
    return await this.movieModel
        .find({ $or: [{ director: user. name }, { producer: user. name }] })
```